# azuracast album art script

Tags: javascript, albumart

Need some help with a album art script for azuracast.
My script works but i want to get the image file, now i only get the url of the image.

```
var nowPlayingTimeout;
var nowPlaying;
function loadNowPlaying() {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'https://demo.azuracast.com/api/nowplaying/1.',
        success: function(np) {
            nowPlaying = np;
              $('.current-album span').text("" + np.now_playing.song.art);
            nowPlayingTimeout = setTimeout(loadNowPlaying, 15000);
        }
    }).fail(function() {
        nowPlayingTimeout = setTimeout(loadNowPlaying, 30000);
    });
}

$(function() {
    loadNowPlaying();
});
```

the code seems to be for text only